# Does "tech" include non-computer technology?

Tags: word-usage

"Tech" appears to be short for "technology". However, I noticed that "tech" is mostly used to describe the computer hardware and software industries.

Suppose I have a few friends who work with technology:

1. W is a biochemist involved in improving fertilizers.
2. X is a mechanical engineer involved in improving the efficiency of oil drilling rigs.
3. Y develops lightweight composite materials for use in bridges.
4. Z is involved with building low-cost sounding rockets.

Can I say that W, X, Y, and Z work in "tech"? Is it appropriate to use "tech" to describe mechanical technology and chemical technology?

When people say "I work in tech", do they only mean "I make software"? Or can it also mean "I build advanced coal mining equipment" or "I develop more efficient fertilizers"?

Answer (score 1):

Technology is the application of scientific knowledge.  Tech is an abbreviation of that but it's fair to say that in general usage it refers to electronics, computing, microprocessors etc.
Using tech outside those fields has fallen redundant.